# getting error while moving to back screen , A FocusNode was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a form for new product...it working well but after save button when I moved to back screen which showing all products...

There is no error but in console it is showing *A FocusNode was used after being disposed*

this error appears in console when I move to back with appbar's back arrow

here is my code

```
class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'editproductscreen';

  @override
  State<EditProductScreen> createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _pricefocusnode = FocusNode();
  final _titlefocusnode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionfocusnode = FocusNode();
  final _imageurlcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final _imageurlfocusnode = FocusNode();
  var _tempproduct =
      Product(description: '', title: '', id: '', price: 0, imageUrl: '');
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pricefocusnode.dispose();
    _titlefocusnode.dispose();
    _descriptionfocusnode.dispose();
    _imageurlcontroller.dispose();
    _imageurlfocusnode.dispose();
    _imageurlfocusnode.removeListener(_updateimage);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageurlfocusnode.addListener(_updateimage);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _updateimage() {
    if (!_imageurlfocusnode.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _saverecord() {
    final result = _form.currentState?.validate();
    if (!result!) return;
    _form.currentState?.save();

    Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .addproduct(_tempproduct);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Product Screen'),
        actions: [IconButton(onPressed: _saverecord, icon: Icon(Icons.save))],
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _form,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: _imageurlcontroller.text.isEmpty
                    ? Center(
                        child: Text(
                        'Enter url',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                      ))
                    : Center(
                        child: Text('Done',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15))),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 12),
                  label: Text('Title'),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                focusNode: _titlefocusnode,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_pricefocusnode);
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _tempproduct = Product(
                    description: _tempproduct.description,
                    title: value.toString(),
                    price: _tempproduct.price,
                    imageUrl: _tempproduct.imageUrl,
                    id: '',
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Cant allow Empty title';

                  return null;
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  label: Text('Price'),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                focusNode: _pricefocusnode,
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionfocusnode);
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _tempproduct = Product(
                    description: _tempproduct.description,
                    title: _tempproduct.title,
                    price: double.parse(value.toString()),
                    imageUrl: _tempproduct.imageUrl,
                    id: '',
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Enter Number';

                  if (double.tryParse(value.toString()) == null)
                    return 'Enter proper double number';

                  if (double.parse(value.toString()) < 0)
                    return 'Enter greater than 0';
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  label: Text('Description'),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                focusNode: _descriptionfocusnode,
                maxLines: 3,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _tempproduct = Product(
                    description: value.toString(),
                    title: _tempproduct.title,
                    price: _tempproduct.price,
                    imageUrl: _tempproduct.imageUrl,
                    id: '',
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  label: Text('ImageUrl'),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                controller: _imageurlcontroller,
                focusNode: _imageurlfocusnode,
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  _saverecord();
                },

                //todo CONFUSION HERE ON ALL ONSAVED METHOD CREATING OBJECT
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _tempproduct = Product(
                    description: _tempproduct.description,
                    title: _tempproduct.title,
                    price: _tempproduct.price,
                    imageUrl: value.toString(),
                    id: '',
                  );
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) return 'Enter url';

                  if (!value.startsWith('http')) return 'not a proper url';

                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
}
```

and one more thing...

TextFormField's onSaved has very similar code..is there any other way to make it shorter.. I have to put in all textformfield with little change

Answer (score 0):

In this method you are calling it to set state if the focus node does not have a focus by adding an ! in the condition check

```
void _updateimage() {
    if (!_imageurlfocusnode.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

remove the ! from the if condition. It should look like

```
void _updateimage() {
    if (_imageurlfocusnode.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

Comment: ! it is used as I want to display image in container whenever focus is lost from that textfield